# C# Add items to listView

Tags: c#

Hello i need help adding items to my listview im using this:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Person newPerson = new Person()
            {
                Name = txtName.Text,
                Age = txtAge.Text,
                Gender = txtGender.Text,
                Photo = txtPhoto.Text
            };
            string[] row = { txtName.Text, txtAge.Text, txtGender.Text, txtPhoto.Text};
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row);
            lvPersons.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

This is working but i want to use my class person to add and not this line:

```
string[] row = { txtName.Text, txtAge.Text, txtGender.Text, txtPhoto.Text};
```

because using the line above im not making use of this: (i think)

```
Person newPerson = new Person()
            {
                Name = txtName.Text,
                Age = txtAge.Text,
                Gender = txtGender.Text,
                Photo = txtPhoto.Text
            };
```

Can someone help me adding items with my class i have tested with this:

```
string[] row = { Name, Age, Gender, Photo };
```

and this

```
string[] row = {Person Name, Person  Age, Person  Gender, Person  Photo };
```

but both give me errors i need some help

Comment: Do you mean `ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new [] {newPerson.Name, newPerson.Age, newPerson.Gender, newPerson.Photo});`?

Comment: try {newPerson.Name, newPerson.Age, newPerson.Gender, newPerson.Photo}

Comment: Both work thanks!!, omg so simple, thank you to both of you

Comment: @diiN_ no that don't work

Comment: @Grant Winney , Done! im new here sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

It's working with:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new [] {newPerson.Name, newPerson.Age, newPerson.Gender, newPerson.Photo});
```

Thanks to @René Vogt for the help/solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
            string[] row = { "1000", "2000", "3000", "4000" };
            List<string> lvPersons = new List<string>();

            foreach (var item in row)
            {
                lvPersons.Add(item);
            }
```

Comment: already got it with@René Vogt comment: `ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new [] {newPerson.Name, newPerson.Age, newPerson.Gender, newPerson.Photo});`